# Python - substitute parts of C programs, but skip comments

Tags: python, regex

using Python and regular expressions I need to add one space on either side of each assignment operator in C programs, but skip the operators in comments:

```
int x;
int y=100;
x=y;
// a=b+c
/* i=j+k */
```

the above needs to be translated to:

```
int x;
int y = 100;
x = y;
// a=b+c
/* i=j+k */
```

I have tried with this regex to skip single line comments:

```
try:
    source = re.sub(r'(?<!//)(.*)([^\s])=([^\s])', r'\1\2 = \3', source)
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

but it is not working.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, [this demo](http://ideone.com/fpKMwR) is not 100% safe, but can give you a jumpstart.

Comment: If you want to account for multi-line comments, you're going to need to implement some kind of state machine to track when a multi-line comment starts and when it ends.

Comment: Do you have indentations in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is a bit more difficult than you probably think. Consider that C has operators `!=`, `==`, `+=`, `-=` and so on. There may be strings `"a=b"`, `char`s `'='` and even `short`s and `int`s like `'=='` and `'===='`. Comments may be multiline. You should also assert that C code is correct.

It's impossible to do so using regular expressions.

Try to use simple state machines idea for parsing your C code. I think it's possible to implement it using functions and `if` and `while` operators. You can filter out pieces of code where `=` is not assignment. With a bit more sophisticated code, you can handle operators that include `=` as part of them and, if you wish, to wrap them in spaces too.

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions to introduce spaces in code between comments and strings. Such regexes will look like `(?<=^|\w|\d) ?= ?(?<=^|\w|\d)` which are replaced with `=`. But I'm still not sure that this regex can cover major corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it this way:

```
for line in open("file_to_be_formated.c"):
    li=line.strip()
    if not (li.startswith("//") or li.startswith("/*")):
        # format code
```

A regex that will skip the commented lines is the following one:

```
(?://[^\n]*|/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/)
```

A small example:

```
import re

my_string = """// my single line comment
another random text
/*some multi-line
comment*/
"""

m = re.findall(r'(?://[^\n]*|/\*(?:(?!\*/).)*\*/)', my_string, re.DOTALL)
print(m)
```

The output will be a list with the matched comments:

```
['// my single line comment', '/*some multi-line\ncomment*/']
```

Comment: Line doesn't have to starts with // or /*. You can have: int a=100; // a comment

Comment: This assumes a single line comment. How would you handle multi-line comments?

Comment: @jozef That could be handled within format code by breaking out when the comment starts.

Comment: You should also keep indentations. strip would remove the indentation from the original file.